y_true.shape=(None, None) with custom TimeseriesGenerator for multiple inputs for LSTM model
I'm building LSTM model with tensorflow keras and it requires multiple Input (each has different features) and because of RAM issue, i have to create custom generator for my model:
class CustomTimeseriesGenerator(TimeseriesGenerator):
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    x, y = super().__getitem__(idx)
    x_list = []
    col_index = 0
    for input in input_list:
        input_features = feature_dict[input] //list of feature name for each input
        
        x_input = x[:,:,col_index:col_index+len(input_features)]
        
        x_list.append(x_input)
        col_index = col_index + len(input_features)
    return tuple(x_list), y

Then I will call this custom generator during fitting process
train_gen = CustomTimeseriesGenerator(X.to_numpy(),y.to_numpy(),timesteps,batch_size=batch_size,end_index = train_size)
val_gen = CustomTimeseriesGenerator(X.to_numpy(),y.to_numpy(),timesteps,batch_size=batch_size,start_index = train_size+1)

model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=50)

However, It throws below error when running (model was compiled with tf.keras.metrics.F1Score)
ValueError: FBetaScore expects 2D inputs with shape (batch_size, output_dim), with output_dim fully defined (not None). Received input shapes: y_pred.shape=(None, 3) and y_true.shape=(None, None).

I already tried to use smaller data (without generator) and it works fine, both y_pred and y_true shape are (None, 3) then it seems that there is no issue with model implementation but data generator only.
I have changed my solution from generator to timeseries_dataset_from_array following below answer
Split tensorflow BatchDataset for LSTM with multiple inputs
It works well but i still want to know root cause of my issue to prevent for future
